# How to provide default value in Wagtail Page.title field?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, wagtail

All I need is just randomly generated page title, something among the lines:

```
class MyBasePage(Page):
    title = models.CharField(
        default=uuid4,
        verbose_name=_('title'),
        max_length=255,
        help_text=_("The page title as you'd like it to be seen by the public")
    )

class OtherPage(MyBasePage):
    pass
```

Currently I'm blocked by the following error:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'title' in class 'MyBasePage' clashes with field of the same name from base class 'Page'.

Any ideas how to achieve this? 
For the convenience here's [url](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/core/models.py) to the source code.

Comment: Can you add the code for the "Page" model? Looks like you may have a "title" field in Page, so your title in MyBasePage is causing the conflict.

Comment: @f71316 Added source code url.

Comment: You can't just override the base Page class' "title" field by placing a new conflicting "title" in the MyBasePage class.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted

Perhaps use your save function to look for an existing title and set the default to a uuid there if it doesn't exist...

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to overwrite the `title` property that comes with a Wagtail Page and you'll receive this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'title' in class 'MyBasePage' clashes with field of the same name from base class 'Page'.
```

If you want to overwrite Wagtail `title` default value you could set it with this snippet of code (the last line is the important one):

```
class MyBasePage(Page):
    # Custom fields in here ...

MyBasePage._meta.get_field("title").default = "New Default Title"
```

Lastly, Note that the last line is outside of the defined Class — That's how we get away with changing the default title in a single line of code.

Comment: Be careful with this solution. Modifying the default value like this will result in a new migration file being created for wagtailcore app and added as a dependency for subsequent migration files in your custom app. Reinstalling or updating wagtail will result in deletion of that migration file in wagtailcore, thus missing parent node error will be raised.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the pre_init signal of model

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_init
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyBasePage)
def generate_home_title(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.title = randomly_title()
```